# get x cell in range google sheets app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using a google sheets apps script, Is it possible to get the X cell in a range of cells as shown below:

```js
var app = SpreadsheetApp;
var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

var cells = sheet.getRange("D6:BF100"); // the range

for (var x = 0; x < 100; i++) {
var cell = cells[row][x]; // this is the line that doesn't work

if (someCondition(x)) {
      cell.setBackground("red");
}
}
```

I don't want to change the colors for every single cell, just the ones that have the correct condition.

I know it is possible to do something like this:

```js
var cell = sheet.getRange(row+i);
```

But this method takes a very long time to complete the for loop as there are hundreds of cells that need to be scanned. I would rather only use getRange once with the entire range (instead of just one cell at a time) and then from that range (it should make a 2d array right?) set the cell values. I think that would be a lot faster.

Is there a different way to do it faster, or do I just need to do this: `var cell = cells[row][x];` a different way.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you read best practices ? See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: @TheMaster yes I have read it. I was looking through mainly the optimizing one, and unfortunately in their example they are only getting the range of a single cell.

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations)? They're getting a whole range and not a single cell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your for loop is constructed incorrectly. You increment the variable i that isn't defined or used anywhere. Also, you use the variable row without defining it.

It takes forever because it has to query your sheet each time you call `cells.getRange()` Instead, you can query once using `cells.getValues()` to get the whole range, and then change the cells color that meet the condition one at a time.

Try the following;

```
var app = SpreadsheetApp;
var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

var cells_range = sheet.getRange("D6:BF100");
var cells_values = cells_range.getValues();

for (var col = 1; col <= cells_values[0].length; col++) {
  for (var row = 1; row <= cells_values.length; row++) {
    if (someCondition(cells_values[row][col])) {
      cells_range.getCell(row, col).setBackground("red");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The for loop is constructed correctly. I had to edit it slightly for the question to make more sense. I seem to have forgotten to change the i++ to x++. Also the row variable is just a number for what row the for loop is currently on.

Your answer still did answer my question, though, because I was unaware of the cells_range.getCell(row, col) which was what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is just my own answer to help users who might get to this question.

Once you have a range of cells, like this:

`var range = sheet.getRange("your range");`

You can do this to get a specific cell:

`var cell = range.getCell(row, col);`